# Code autocomplete not working in the debug console of pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

When I enter into the debug mode and type something in the python debug console, it doesn't show the popup menu with suggestions. It shows suggestions only when one presses the `TAB`. How can I make the popups to show up automatically, just like in the editor?

[image]